# References for the foundations of mathematics

Tags: foundations

I´m a physicist and I´d like to learn about deep questions on the foundations of mathematics. I´m looking for a acessible introduction written in a language a physicist could understand, and then build up from there until I have a relatively good bird´s-eye view. Any hints?

Comment: [Classic Set Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Classic-Set-Theory-Independent-Mathematics/dp/0412606100) is a very nice introduction.

Comment: And if you know some category theory, check out [Sets for Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/Sets-Mathematics-F-William-Lawvere/dp/0521010608).